# Loading a jrxml file under Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I have a web app that uses *JasperReports* to power data export to Excel, PDF & CSV. It's a grails app using the *DynamicJasperReports* plugin and it uses a jrxml file as the template for the report.

This was working but has broken following some changes to our tomcat configuration. It still works locally in grails development mode.

```
FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder()
drb.setTemplateFile("resources/reportTemplate.jrxml")

DynamicReport report = reportBuilder.call(drb)

JRDataSource ds = new JRMapCollectionDataSource(data)

JasperPrint jp = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(report, new ClassicLayoutManager(), ds)
ReportWriter reportWriter = ReportWriterFactory.getInstance().getReportWriter(jp, format, [:])
reportWriter.writeTo(response)
```

It throws this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperDesign(DynamicJasperHelper.java:151)
at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(DynamicJasperHelper.java:448)
at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(DynamicJasperHelper.java:234)
at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(DynamicJasperHelper.java:187)
at com.giivpro.services.analytics.JasperReportsService.runReport(JasperReportsService.groovy:30)
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually realized this was not due to upgrading to tomcat7 as I originally thought but instead was due to changes in how the app was being deployed, made around the same time.

All the jar file dependencies of the app are now copied to /var/lib/tomcat/lib rather than being deployed inside the war file.  Which means that the line in DynamicJasperHelper

```
URL url = DynamicJasperHelper.class.getClassLoader().getResource(dr.getTemplateFileName());
```

now failed due to security restrictions on the ClassLoader. The jars in /var/lib/tomcat/lib get loaded by a separate ClassLoader and are not able to load resources from specific WAR files.

Comment: If you get a font not found issue after that, on AWS Ubuntu, sudo apt-get install dejavu*